# request parameters in action outcome are ISO-8859-1 encoded instead of UTF-8

Tags: jsf, redirect, character-encoding, glassfish

I have a problem encoding the outcome of an action method into UTF-8 using.

Glassfish 3.1.2 is set to UTF-8: `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>` and entering following UTF-8 encoded url into the browser results in correct decoded view-parameter retrieval in the bean/converter.

`/sites/foo.xhtml?paramKey=Getr%C3%A4nke` -> `/sites/foo.xhtml?paramKey=Getränke`

`Getränke` is retrieved correctly in the backing bean and my converters can retrieve the correct objects.

**Problem:**

Within a bean method that is invoked by a command component view parameters are appended to the targeted view-id that will be returned.

```
public String action()
{
    return "/sites/foo.xhtml?paramKey=Getränke&faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Will result in an ISO-8859-1 encoded url instead of UTF-8 encoded after the redirect:

`/sites/foo.xhtml?paramKey=Getr%E4nke`

**Did I missed to define UTF-8 somewhere?**

Or do I manually have to encode the outcome to UTF-8 myself, which works. Strangely the basic links like `h:link` work fine.

**System:**

Glassfish 3.1.2
Mojarra 3.1.23
Primefaces 3.5f
Omnifaces: 1.6 snapshot

Note: also removed `PrettyURL` or `//Rewrite` for testing to make sure this cannot be the reason.

Note: for testing also added following to a filter:

```
if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported exactly this issue more than a year ago: [issue 2440](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2440). Unfortunately, they fixed it for 2.2 only instead of 2.1 as it required a JSF spec change. As you're already using OmniFaces, you could also use its [`Faces#redirect()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#redirect%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) instead. It uses explicitly UTF-8 to URL-encode the parameters.

```
public void action() throws IOException {
    Faces.redirect("sites/foo.xhtml?paramKey=%s", "Getränke");
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for that info, did not found that issue. Free open-source: a love-hate continues. I am at 99% for my prototype to go online and i am so stuck at the last 1% since such big bugs occur. Just a single change going from id's to seo-friendly urls results in such big problems. Before I change my code everywhere are there known problems with jsf2.2 on glassfish 3, since I would prefer this. (Testing with 2.1.25 resulted in a new bug concerning flash with the same use-case of my question)

Comment: Flash issue is fixed in 2.1.26 (scheduled at 4 or 5 sept, you can if necessary grab 2.1.26 snapshot or patch Mojarra yourself (we did for zeef.com)). I recommend to stay away from 2.2 as long as you're still on PrimeFaces 3.

Comment: You mean glassfish 3?

Comment: No, PrimeFaces 3 is not compatible with Mojarra 2.2.

Comment: Oh okay, good to know. Great thanks did not knew what I would have done without you and omnifaces.

Comment: Since i am redirecting now I need to use `ViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(...)` since i am rewriting url's which seems to result in the same issue. You know a workaround for this too? Now I also get a `�` and my log says that the bookmarkable url results in: `Getr%EF%BF%BDnke` (UTF-8 + ISO) Maybe I should decode the ISO-Code in my converters. It is not critical for my application since the critical view-params do not use characters that need to be escaped but still, just very annoying right now.

Comment: Oh, it has indeed the same problem. This is unfortunate.

Comment: You know if this is also fixed in 2.2+? Else I will open an issue.

Comment: Based on Mojarra 2.2.2 source code, no. Only `ExternalContextImpl#encodeRedirectURL()` has been fixed, the `encodeBookmarkableURL()` and `encodePartialActionURL()` aren't fixed. Edit: I posted a comment on 2440 for the sake that. But yes please report a new one yourself.